# Setting up Android C2DM App Server

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I've built an android application [a knowledge exchange forum, inspired by none other than stackoverflow :) ] that communicates with a remote (free) server. As of now, the application fetches/refreshes content on user demand.

I'd like to implement push notifications, so that a user can be notified when someone posts an answer to his/her question. I've heard that C2DM is a good push notification service for Android devices. The client code I can perhaps take care of, it's the server side programming that has me completely baffled. I don't even know where to start.

The capabilities of the server as listed are CGI, PHP, ASP.NET, SSI, FrontPage Extensions, Perl and Python. I'm currently using PHP scripts to run SQL queries on a MySQL database and transmit data to the client (android device). What feature(s) of the server must I use to implement C2DM? Is it even feasible with the given capabilities?

Push notifications would greatly enhance the functionality and usability of my application. I request you to provide guidance on setting up the server.

Thanks in advance for your response.

EDIT: A difference I've noticed is that while I'm using a WEB Server, http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/ constantly refers to a 3rd party APPLICATION server. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I use c2dm push messages via Python Google App Engine. You will need oauth to get your c2dm credentials authenticated into a token and then just http get to actually fire off the c2dm message to the c2dm servers...

This will convert your credentials into a key you can use:

```
def get_auth_key():
 mk = __name__+".authkey"
 form_fields = {
        "accountType": "HOSTED",
        "Email": constants.c2dm_email,
        "Passwd": constants.c2dm_pwd,
        "service":constants.c2dm_service, ## ( c2dm_service = "ac2dm" )
        "source": constants.c2dm_source,
    }
  form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields)
  result = urlfetch.fetch(url=constants.client_auth_url,
                            payload=form_data,
                            method=urlfetch.POST,
                            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

  d = dict()
  fields=result.content.split("\n")
  for r in fields:
        if "=" in r:
            (k,v)=r.split("=")
            d[k]=v
            logging.debug(result)           

  logging.debug("Not in memcache :-(" )
  auth = d["Auth"]
  logging.debug("Now got key %s " % auth)
  memcache.set(mk,auth)
  return auth
```

Then just use that with the c2dm key you got from the Android client registration and you're all good... (please excuse the app engine logging / memcache stuff).

Comment: How exactly will an app running on the Google App Engine interface with my database? Won't the app need to know when content is posted to the database, so that it broadcasts out a notification?

Comment: You can use any internet connected server... it's just that my choice was GAE. As long as your server can receive the incoming c2dm keys from the Android client upon registration and do some form of oauth then you are good to go... I just had "issues" with the conversion of username+password credentials to a key suitable for using against the C2DM push servers. Does that make sense/

Comment: I just used GAE for this example but any internet connected server will do. You will just need it to (1) receive the c2dm registration keys from the android client and (2) convert the c2dm credentials you have to a key and then (3) use (1)+(2) to send that client a message. Does that help ?

Comment: When a device (client) registers for C2DM (it's registration ID sent to my database), is it possible to send some other data along as well? Like the username of the user logged into my application...

Comment: yes that's precisely what you need to do so that you can associate your internal ID with the "key" that will be used to c2dm a message to that client.

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented C2DM push notification feature completely in java. In order to have the complete push ecosystem we did following

1. Code changes on client side to get the registration key.
2. Provide a service using which Android client application can send device registration key to our in house servers.  We deployed a simple web service on tomcat which takes in registration key as post parameter. and then persist in the MySQL database.
3. For sending push message we created a standalone java application, which reads the registration keys from MySQL and then makes a HTTP post request to Google c2dm server. Our application is multithreaded so that it can make multiple POST request to Google servers simultaneously.

Alternatively, you can also look at products such as urban air ship.

Comment: 1. Understood. 2. The web service could be a PHP script right? Which the application POSTs to? 3. Unfortunately, right over my head :( Could you please elaborate? Where should the Java app run? The server we use is free, and only provides us cPanelX as an interface to control our activities. How exactly do I implement the functionality of a Java application?

Comment: 2. Web service could be any language as long as you can capture  and store the registration token.
3. The java app will run in your hosting environment. In our case we deployed the java application on Linux box. We wrote a shell script which launched our application. Then we scheduled our shell script to launch every 30 min. Your java application will basically do 2 things 1. Read all the registration keys which are stored in mysql. 2. Make a http post request to google server using the key and message text. 

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Comment: Oh woah wait a minute - can I use Cron jobs to schedule a script to run every (say) 15 minutes, which checks the database for registration keys and sends the intended recipient the relevant data? I don't think the server will allow me to run Java code, but I could use any other language right (PHP/Perl/Python)?

Comment: You can use any language you like , the bottom line is somehow make a http post request to google server with all the data elements as defined here 

http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#push

Answer (score 0):

It's very important that you have a low-level socket connection with the push server. Using PHP and mySQL can easily lead to performance issues and overlapping push requests. Cron jobs and launching shell scripts every x minutes should be avoided.

There are also hosted solutions which setup you up directly without having to bother for the serverside implementation, like: [www.urbainairship.com](http://www.urbainairship.com) and the XS2 push server, http://xs2technology.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/xs2-push-notification-platform_a-hosted-solution/